# Error: unexpected '}' in " }" and I don't know what to do

Tags: r

```
    C <- rep(c('F','M'), each = 3, times = 4)
Gender <- NULL
for (i in C) {
  if i == 'F'{
    append(Gender,values = 'Female')
  }
  else {
    append(Gender, values = 'Male')
  }
}
```

and it shows Error: unexpected '}' in " }"

what should I fix in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from `if i == 'F'`

```r
C <- rep(c('F','M'), each = 3, times = 4)
Gender <- NULL
for (i in C) {
  if (i == 'F'){ # The condition has to be wrapped by ()
    Gender <- append(Gender,values = 'Female')  # Reassign to Gender
  } else { # It's better to put else this way 
    Gender <- append(Gender, values = 'Male') 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But now I got another problem which there is no variable in Gender. After running the code. What I wanted was putting 'Female' or 'Male' variables in Gender depending on C. But it only show NULL. Is there any way that I can fix this problem?

Comment: I just edited the post to fill `Gender`